Telerik HTML5 ReportViewer - how to set NoHeader fror CSV export option
I'm having issue to retrieve a nice/neat CSV export from the HTML5 ReportViewer. In other Report methods, there are NoHeader, NoStaticText parameters for CSV export. Those 2 can eliminate the column text. How do I set these 2 params in HTML5 ReportViewer?
var repname = $("#RepportName").val()
var Params = CollectParam();

$("#cur_reportViewer").telerik_ReportViewer({
    serviceUrl: "/domain/report/",
    templateUrl: "templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html",
    reportSource: {
        report: initReport,
        parameters: Params
    },
    //viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewModes.INTERACTIVE,
    viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewModes.PRINT_PREVIEW,
    scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.SPECIFIC,
    scale: 1.0,
    enableAccessibility: false,
    sendEmail: { enabled: false },
});

I've read Telerik doc "https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/embedding-reports/display-reports-in-applications/web-application/html5-report-viewer/api-reference/report-viewer-initialization" and is not able to figure out where to add/modify these 2 options.
Or there is a way to to export CSV to a more properly format?
TIA.
